# Closure of a topological space $Y$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $Y \subseteq X$. Prove that $\overline{Y} = \displaystyle\bigcap_{F \textrm{ is closed and }Y\subseteq F} F$.

$x \in \overline{Y}$ iff for all $U$ open set in $X$ such that $x \in U$ satisfy $Y \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: You have to add your definition of closure, otherwise the question does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in \overline{Y} \Rightarrow \forall$ open set $U$ satisfy $U \cap Y \neq \emptyset$. Let $Z$ be a close set such that $Y \subseteq Z$. Suppose $x \notin Z$, then $x \in X \setminus Z$, that is a open set. Therefore $\exists U_0 = X \setminus Z$ a open set such that $x \in U_0$, then $U_0 \cap Y = \emptyset$. This is a contradiction, because $x \in \overline{Y}$.